# drawer item won't be clicked with nested layout

Tags: android, layout, drawer

I can't click on drawer items with this nested layout

Only if I move the DrawerLayout at the end of all other view I can click on its items but in this case all other view overlap the drawer

What is the correct way to add a drawer into a nested layout like this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#111"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_sky">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">



            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/cityTV"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:clickable="true"

                android:gravity="left"
                android:hint="@string/cityhint"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine|textFilter|textVisiblePassword|textNoSuggestions"
                android:shadowColor="@color/text_shadow"
                android:shadowDx="1"
                android:shadowDy="1"
                android:shadowRadius="6"
                android:textColor="@color/light_font"
                android:textColorHint="@color/grey_font"
                android:textSize="60sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:alpha="0.7">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/alarmView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/alarm" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/internetConn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/closeButton"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/alarmView"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/alarmView"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/internet" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/soundIcon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/closeButton"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/internetConn"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/internetConn"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/sound" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/closeButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:alpha="1"
                android:background="@drawable/common_full_open_on_phone"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:onClick="closeApp"
                android:text="@string/closeButton" />


        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_above="@id/footer"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/precipMM_value_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/descrTV"
                android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tempC_value"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:text="@string/nodata" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/descrTV"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/precipMM_value_tv"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:text="@string/nodata" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/obsTime_value"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/descrTV"
                android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/descrTV"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:text="@string/nodata" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tempC_value"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:shadowColor="@color/text_shadow"
                android:shadowDx="1"
                android:shadowDy="1"
                android:shadowRadius="6"
                android:text="@string/nodata"
                android:textColor="@color/light_font"
                android:textIsSelectable="false"
                android:textSize="80dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>





    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/address_progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:indeterminate="true"

        android:visibility="gone" />


</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Are your items in the foreground? have you tried bringToFront(). Also try setting clickable to true.

Comment: The Drawer must be the last View in the DrawerLayout, outside of any other ViewGroup. It sounds like you may have had it inside the RelativeLayout. It should be listed after the RelativeLayout's closing tag.

Comment: Hi Mike, I tried to move DrawerLayout after the last RelativeLayout but I got "multiple root tags" error.. What is the right way?

Comment: Hi Laith I solved with drawerView.bringToFront(); Thank you